# Tiling an Android XML Drawable

Tags: android, xml, bitmap, drawable

**Is it possible to create an XML Drawable in Android that consists of an other XML Drawable, repeated in tiles?**

I's easy for a png-based-Bitmap:

```
<bitmap
    android:src="@drawable/tile"
    android:tileMode="repeat" />
```

However, Android only alows references to png-files here.

If `@drawable/tile` references another XML-Drawable, the App crashes with an `XmlPullParserException` ("bitmap requires a valid 'src' attribute")

Is there any other way to get a tiled drawable?

Comment: What is your drawable , is it a custom shape or something?

Comment: A layer-list consisting of colored rectangles. But I'm looking for a solution where one can use any XML Drawable, independent of it's content.

Comment: @Philipp , did you ever find an answer to your question?  I've found some ways to do this with Java instead of XML via creating a bitmap *from* the drawable at runtime, but that seems kind of hacky. It'd be nice to find a purely XML solution that's as concise to tile a shape drawable as easy as it is to tile a bitmap.

Comment: No, I never figured it out.